# Python - neglecting to re-initiate while loop

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in my college's introductory csci course that is a mini-diagnosis of a user's symptoms. Everything is working as it should be, except for one thing: if the initial condition that makes the program run (whether or not the user has a fever) is "no" or "n", the program will not re-initiate when the variable that makes the while loop run is redefined.

Instead, the program continues after having received the input from the user of whether to re-initiate the program or not instead of restarting the while loop. This creates problems because the program comes to the next line of code and reaches an undefined variable.

This only happens during the first if, else statement, and has no problem in subsequent statements. It only happens *the first time* the while loop variable is redefined. At all other times, it works.

Even though the first "else" redefines "finished" which should make the while loop restart, it does not restart. However, for each subsequent time that "finished" is redefined by the user, the while loop *does* re-initiate. Odd. Indentation error? I don't know. Double-asterisk is where the while loop needs to re-initiate, but doesn't. It keeps trying to continue regardless of user input, and an error comes up saying "cough" is not defined, indicating that the while loop is not restarting.

here is my code:

```
#Proj2.py

finished = "y"
while finished == "y":   

    print()
    print("Fever Diagnostic Tool")
    print("---------------------")
    print()
    print("Please note that this program performs no true diagnostic \nactivity. No decisions should be made based upon the tool's \nanalysis. If users have a fever, they should contact their \ndoctor.")
    print()
    print()

    FirstDiagnosis = str(input("Do you have a fever (y/n): ")).lower()
    print(FirstDiagnosis)
    if FirstDiagnosis == "y":
        cough = ""
        cough = str(input("Are you coughing (y/n): ")).lower()
        print(cough)
    else:  
        print()
        print("Symptoms")
        print("* None")
        print()
        print("Diagnosis")
        print("    Insufficient information to list possibilites.")
        print()
        print()
        **finished = str(input("Would you like another set of symptoms? ")).lower()**
        print()
    if cough == "y":
        ShortOfBreath = ""
        ShortOfBreath = str(input("Are you short of breath or wheezing or coughing up phlem (y/n): ")).lower()
        print(ShortOfBreath)
```

Comment: I like that your program feels the need to add a disclaimer ;-)

Comment: semantically, I'd say `while finished != "y"`

Comment: please edit your code at the very beginning.. I assume `finished = "y" while finished == "y":` is part of the code, which needs more indentation then

Comment: @pynchia I have an edit pending for that ...

Comment: Start a new script. Experiment with loops. You should be able to understand in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how while loops work. They don't quit as soon as the condition becomes false anywhere in the body; the condition is evaluated only at the end of the block, at which time it decides whether to loop again (if the condition still holds) or to break (if it doesn't).

In this case, the easiest thing to do is to use the `break` statement explicitly:

```
finished = input("Would you like another set of symptoms? ").lower()
if finished == 'y':
    break
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be break when input is not "y"?